# Is there any way to cleanly cancel asynchronous 'prompt' while it is waiting for input?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prompt

I'm working -- as an exercise -- on a Javascript game that involves a sequence of questions.  I'm simply running it in Node, outputting to the console at the moment.  I handle user input using the `prompt` package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt).

All works fine except I also need to set a timeout on the length of time it takes to answer the question, and if the user exceeds that time, then move on to the next question.  However at that point I am in the middle of `prompt` waiting for a response, and when I simply move on I start getting odd side effects, like typed input on the next round doubling up (and then on the next timeout tripling up) -- i.e. an `s` typed in yields `ss`on the console.

Is there anyway with this package to cancel a prompt that is waiting for input?   I looked through the documentation and didn't see a way.  If not, do you know of a package that might provide this capability -- I looked and so far haven't found one.

I don't know if code helps, as the issue seems to be with the package itself, but here is what I'm doing:

A call for user input:

```
this.getUserName = function (callback) {

        var schema = {
            properties: {
                name: {
                    description: "Tu nombre por favor:",
                    pattern: /^[áÁóÓíÍéÉñÑa-zA-Z\s\-]+$/,
                    message: 'Solo letras, por favor',
                    required: true
                }
            }
        };
        prompt.get(schema, callback);
    };
```

when I call this I set up a timer using `setTimeout`

```
 this.timer = setTimeout(this.timedOut.bind(this), this.ROUND_TIME);
        this.prompter.getUserResponse(this.checkAnswer.bind(this));
```

when the timer times out I simply go on to a different piece of code, doing nothing to the prompt (which is still waiting), as I don't know how to "cancel" it…

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to make it work with the NPM `prompt` package, but the package `prompt-improved` seems to have a timeout capability, although it's not well-documented.